# Why NamedTuple of same types are not compatible?

Tags: crystal-lang

Why NamedTuple of the same type are not compatible?

```
alias Data = NamedTuple(
  title: String?
)

data : Data = { title: nil }     # Explicitly specifying that 
                                 # it has ` : Data` type 

proc = ->(data : Data){ p data } 
proc.call data                   # And yet it says it's not 
                                 # of `Data` type
```

Error

```
Error: type must be NamedTuple(title: String | Nil), not NamedTuple(title: Nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect: `data : Data` restricts the type of the local variable to `Data` (which is an alias for `NamedTuple(title: String | Nil)`). This type restriction does not affect the value assignment on the right hand side. The literal value `{type: nil}` is typed as `NamedTuple(title: Nil)`. This type is compatible with the type restriction to `Data`, so it can be assigned to the variable.

This implicitly covariant type restriction does not apply with proc types. I'm not sure about the reasoning behind that. It seems that this should be able to work. So maybe it just needs to be implemented.

You can however explicitly cast `NamedTuple(Nil)` to `NamedTuple(String | Nil)`:

```
alias Data = NamedTuple(
  title: String?
)

data = { title: nil }.as(Data) # Cast named tuple to Data

proc = ->(data : Data){ p data } 
proc.call data
```

However, it is usually not a good idea to work with named tuples as regular data types.  They are only recommended for very specific use cases such as named arguments. Defining custom structs (for example using the record macro) is a better idea and gives you a more powerful and flexible data type.
I'd implement your example like this:

```
record Data,
  title : String?

data = Data.new(title: nil)

proc = ->(data : Data){ p data } 
proc.call data
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it works with plain classes but not with the record, is it a bug? Please check this short example https://gist.github.com/alexeypetrushin/0587e5f74ee4fd8195f3e313badc30cc

Comment: You're simply missing a white space in the macro arguments: `plot : Plot`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, please report it in the issue tracker. Thank you!